# What should I do with this thinning cedar hedge?

Tags: hedge, thinning, cedar

Thanks for your thoughts on this;

We have a line of cedars at our fence, probably 12 feet tall. The fence is is not solid so the trees provide some critical privacy. The problem is, they get almost no sun on one side, shaded by our outdoor kitchen. As such, they are thinning substantially on the one side (bare) but thriving on the sunny side (neighbors side).

To complicate things, the neighbors hate them and keep trimming them back.

What do you think I should I do here?

Thanks again,

Greg[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trees are either Chamaecyparis or Cupressoyparis (Leyland cypress) - cones will enable an exact ID. If they are the latter, these get very large indeed, and will be an ongoing problem for your neighbours in respect of both height and width, and for you in respect of access to keep them pruned to a reasonable height. The trees appear to be growing in a narrow space in front of the metal bars of the fence; they will not only be short of sunlight, but any light at all, and those are not great conditions for any plant to grow in.

I'd suggest you remove the trees completely and put up a solid barrier along the boundary like a fence or similar; however, this won't solve a privacy problem if the upper parts of the trees were screening you from being overlooked.